# Microdata Rich Snippets Showing On Home Page?

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets

I added the schema.org rich snippets code inside the `<head>` and the text is showing up on my home page, what am I doing wrong?

DTD

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

...

Snippet Code

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EntertainmentBusiness">
       <span itemprop="name">MySite.com</span>
       <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span> stars -
            based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">233</span> Reviews
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, where is your `head` element?

Comment: @unor I haven't posted the whole <head> section... just the important bits relating to the issue

Answer (score 1):

`div` is not allowed in `head`.

Parser’s think that the `body` started since they encounter `div`, so this content is displayed.

See "Content model" for the allowed content of the [`head` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element).

Comment: The code is from Schema.org and it uses Divs in the head of the document - any solutions to get it working correctly?

Comment: @ubique: Could you link to such an example?

Comment: @ubique: These are not in the `head` element.

Answer (score -1):

The correct DTD to use for XHTML and MicroData is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional with HTML5 microdata//EN" "xhtml1-transitional-with-html5-microdata.dtd">
```

Found a code example from schema.org that uses the ['meta'](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing) tag - although it's not recommended from an SEO point of view according to the articles I have read:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
  <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
  <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
    Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
  </div>
</div>
```